# How does `valueB` work? It always returns the same value?

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

Consider the following code:

```
module Main where

import Control.Event.Handler
import Reactive.Banana
import Reactive.Banana.Frameworks

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (addHandler, fire) <- newAddHandler
  compile (network addHandler) >>= actuate
  fire "fire one"
  fire "fire two"

network :: AddHandler String -> MomentIO ()
network addHandler = do
  fireEvent <- fromAddHandler addHandler
  behavior <- stepper "initial stepper value" fireEvent
  behaviorValue <- valueB behavior
  reactimate $ putStrLn . (\v -> "fire input: " ++ show v) <$> fireEvent
  reactimate $ print behaviorValue <$ fireEvent
```

The output from this program is:

```
fire input: "fire one"
"initial stepper value"
fire input: "fire two"
"initial stepper value"
```

Am I using `valueB` correctly? If not, what am I doing wrong? What is the purpose of `valueB` and when should I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to keep in mind that the `Moment` (and `MomentIO`) monad expresses a computation that happens at a particular moment in time. The combinator `valueB` simply returns the value of the Behavior at that moment. In your case, that is at the very beginning.

If you want to sample the value of a Behavior at different times, you can use the `<@>` and `<@` operators, which are very similar to `<$>` and `<$`. For instance, replacing the last line with

```
reactimate $ print <$> behavior <@ fireEvent
```

will print the value of the Behavior at each moment when the event fires.

A more advanced use would be to use `valueB` with `execute`.

Comment: I eventually came to realize that `valueB` is in the "higher order" section of the documentation for a reason, and it probably most often appears in conjunction with other higher order operations like `switchB`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Buttons840 Yes, exactly. :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, `valueB` obtains the current value of a given behavior. It works in some `MonadMoment`. In this case this "moment" is the time the network is created. For this reason you always get the same value. You are asking for the value only once, at the beginning.

You can't directly react to changes in Behaviors since they don't really notify about their changes (they are continuous signals).

If you want to see `valueB` in action. I think the `execute` function is what you need.

```
execute (valueB <$> stepper "initial stepper value" fireEvent)
```

This is of course a very contrived example, but it should do what you want.

Also, I don't have experience with ReactiveBanana specifically, but most of the FRP frameworks work similarly.